# RabbitHutch.CreateBus() only allows to connect to one RabbitMQ server

Tags: c#, rabbitmq, easynetq

I have an application that needs to connect to 2 different RabbitMQ servers. Calling RabbitHutch.CreateBus(connectionString1) and RabbitHutch.CreateBus(connectionString2) both return an IBus connected to connectionString1. I implemented this workaround but I would like to know from the community if there is a better way to accomplish this or if my approach is valid.

```
var connectionFactory = container.Resolve<IConnectionFactory>();
var logger = container.Resolve<IEasyNetQLogger>();
var eventBus = container.Resolve<IEventBus>();
var connectionConfiguration = container.Resolve<ConnectionConfiguration>();
var persistentConnectionFactory = container.Resolve<IPersistentConnectionFactory>();
var clusterHostSelectionStrategy = container.Resolve<IClusterHostSelectionStrategy<ConnectionFactoryInfo>>();
// override these objects to connect to a different RabbitMQ server
connectionConfiguration = (new ConnectionStringParser()).Parse(configuration["spring:cloud:bus"]);
connectionFactory = new ConnectionFactoryWrapper(connectionConfiguration, clusterHostSelectionStrategy);
persistentConnectionFactory = new PersistentConnectionFactory(logger, connectionFactory, eventBus);
_bus = new RabbitAdvancedBus(
    connectionFactory,
    container.Resolve<IConsumerFactory>(),
    logger,
    container.Resolve<IClientCommandDispatcherFactory>(),
    container.Resolve<IPublishConfirmationListener>(),
    eventBus,
    container.Resolve<IHandlerCollectionFactory>(),
    container,
    connectionConfiguration,
    container.Resolve<IProduceConsumeInterceptor>(),
    container.Resolve<IMessageSerializationStrategy>(),
    container.Resolve<IConventions>(),
    container.Resolve<AdvancedBusEventHandlers>(),
    persistentConnectionFactory);
```

Answer (score 1):

Which DI implementation are you using?

Can you create 2 containers instead? All bus components are registered as singletons, and I wouldn't want to share them between 2 bus instances.

Alternatively you could try creating 2 child scopes from the root container, and registering different bus instances in each container.

Comment: Could you add sample code on how to register a different container for each connection? I see RabbitHutch.SetContainerFactory() but it does not handle this scenario

Comment: I realized the default behavior of CreateBus() is to create a new container every time, no matter if it is the same connection string. I had to change my code to have a default container instance for calls to the most common server, and let it create a new container when using the other connection string.